# Jenkins - keep process alive from first stage until pipeline ends

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cypress

I am running cypress in parallel across a few jenkins agents.  In order to do that, any cypress job has to be able to find a running instance of my app to test against.  Previously, I was doing `npm install` and `npm start & npx wait-on localhost:3000` on *each node*, so that cypress could easily find the app:

```java
parallel {
    stage {
        agent {
            label: 'agent-1'
        }
        steps {
            sh 'npm install --silent'
            sh 'npm start & npx wait-on http://localhost:3000'
            sh "npm run cy:parallel"
        }
    }
    stage {
        agent {
            label: 'agent-2'
        }
        steps {
            // same as above
        }
    }
}
```

Running `npm install` and `npm start & npx wait-on localhost:3000` on each parallel node is fine I guess, but it adds a few minutes to those stages.  I feel like it would be more efficient to run the app on agent-0 (which has ip, say, 2222.2222.2222.2222), then once the app is up and running, just use that as my cypress url:

```java
stage {
    agent {
        label 'agent-0'
    }
    steps {
        sh 'npm install --silent'
        sh 'npm start & npx wait-on http://localhost:3000'
    }
}
stage {
    environment {
        CYPRESS_BASE_URL="http://2222.2222.2222.2222:3000/"
    }
    parallel {
        stage {
            agent {
                label: 'agent-1'
            }
            steps {
                sh "npm run cy:parallel"
            }
        }
        stage {
            agent {
                label: 'agent-2'
            }
            steps {
                sh "npm run cy:parallel"
            }
        }
        stage { } // more parallel stages
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that as soon as `npm start & npx wait-on http://localhost:3000` is complete in the first stage on agent-0, that stage is over, and the processes running there are killed.

How can I keep a process running from a previous stage so that it can be accessed in later stages?